# В чем хранить "деньги"? Float / Double

Tags: java, float, double

Был на собеседовании, спросили, "в переменной какого типа лучше хранить деньги", сказал `Float`, мол скорость, все дела. - забраковали. Ответа на вопрос "почему" не услышал. так вот почему "деньги" нельзя хранить во `Float`?

Comment: погрешность операций. В double ещё кое-как можно, но страшно. Правильный ответ - их НЕЛЬЗЯ хранить в числах с плавающей запятой. Проще всего в long умножив на гарантированную точность (например в копейках или сколько надо). Можно иногда в аналогах decimal пытаться, но лучше не надо. Вы например хотите добавить 1 рубль к 10^10 которые уже есть на счету. Он просто потеряется из-за нормирования.

Comment: @pavel Вот чего вы стесняетесь ответ написать?

Comment: Если в языке есть тип fixed point, то стоит хранить в нем (по поводу Java не в курсе). Если такого типа нет, реализуем через целочисленный тип. Почему нельзя в float хранить, Pavel все верно написал.

Comment: потому что `1.40f - 0.43f == 0.97f` и `1.03d - 0.42d == 0.61d` - `false`.

Comment: long с делением на 100 при выводе, BigDecimal, специализированные классы/библиотеки (Java Money, Joda Money)

Comment: В C#, например, есть специальный тип `decimal` для таких случаев.

Comment: @pavlofff, а не на 10000? У `Currency` же 4 знака.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Для денег важны "копейки". Потеря любой значащей цифры в финансовой сфере недопустима. Поскольку числа хранятся в двоичной системе - почти любое десятичное нецелое число не имеет конечное количество цифр после запятой. Поскольку мы не можем хранить бесконечно большое количество цифр после запятой, часть числа теряется.

Простой пример: 5.1 переведем в двоичный вид

Целая часть имеет только 3 цифры

```
 5₁₀ = 1*2²  + 0*2¹  + 1*2⁰ = 101₂
```

А вот дробная...

```
.1₁₀ = 0*2⁻¹ + 0*2⁻² + 0*2⁻³ + 1*2⁻⁴ + 1*2⁻⁵ + 0*2⁻⁶ + 0*2⁻⁷ + 1*2⁻⁸ + 1*2⁻⁹...
```

Если взять только первые 7 цифр (двоичных) после запятой, получится не `0.1`, а `0.09375`

**Добавлено:** Что касается подходящих типов (поскольку на вопросе тег Java - примеры для него) для хранения финансовых данных, как уже написали в комментариях и соседних ответах есть два подхода:

1. Типы с произвольной точностью (например BigDecimal). В исходники не смотрел но внутри хранение скорее всего происходит или в строках или массивах цифр;
2. Целочисленные примитивные типы (int или long). При этом в переменных финансы хранятся в неделимых единицах измерения (это не всегда копейки/центы, в ряде случаев должны учитываться, например, сотые доли этих единиц)

Как всегда выбор должен определяться спецификой задачи. Типы с произвольной точностью скорее всего будут обрабатываться медленнее чем примитивы, но в случае с примитивами нужно "помнить" что мы в них храним, чтобы при выгрузке в смежные системы не получить астрономические суммы.

Comment: Хороший ответ... Но вопрос "в чем хранить" - укажите типы в которых можно хранить.

Comment: Ответы уже даны, но в комментариях к вопросу. Не думаю что это нужно дублировать. См. комментарии pavel и pavlofff.

Comment: Ответ на вопрос должен отвечать, а не комментарий. Давно вы видимо не видели запись "Коментарии удалены или перемещеный в чат"

Comment: @nick_n_a Убедили :)

Answer (score 19):

Немного, наверное, конкретики можно внести без углубления в тонкости вычислений машины:)
Тут надо еще уточнение, какие операции будут с деньгами производиться.
Для платежей и переводов - достаточен `long`. А сама сумма - в минорных единицах. Потому что мы не платим десятыми долями копеек/центов. Т.е. для `1 руб. 10 копеек`, будем перечислять `110`.
Хранить также можно в таком же типе.
Но уже появляются вопросы, когда надо проводить вычисления. К примеру, насчитать некий процент за месяц. Тут уж типы `double/float`, как заметили некоторые, могут давать погрешности из-за тонкостей стандарта чисел с плавающей запятой. Но есть хороший выход: есть объекты чисел, которые хранят все значения в целых числах. Конкретнее: два целочисленных значения: мантиссу вещественного числа в виде объекта класса большого целочисленного, и неотрицательный десятичный порядок числа типа `int`. Тут напрашивается пример для `Java`: класс `BigDecimal`. Я бы хранил деньги в нем.
Ну а если еще углубиться в расчеты, то для всяких операций есть свои стандарты. Например, если рассчитываем пеню, то округление в большую сторону:
При пене в `1.123456 руб`, получим `1.13`. Все просто.

Если кто нашел в моем ответе ошибку, пожалуйста, поправьте меня. Я только въезжаю в финансовые расчетные операции.

Comment: 1.13 - это просто если его не трогать. Давайте представим что это `float`. Выполните в Java `System.out.println(1.13f + 10000f - 10000f);` Сразу напрашивается вопрос: "Зачем мы это округляли?" :)

Comment: _Я бы хранил деньги в нем._ - Храните деньги в сберегательных кассах, если, конечно, они у вас есть :-D

Comment: @tutankhamun А вы интересный пример предоставили! Получилось 1.1298828. Тут уж интересный и неожиданный, с точки зрения матвычислений, результат. Что еще раз доказывает, что лучше не хранить во float деньги из-за погрешностей в вычислениях. Ну а округление тут все равно одинаковое. Но нет гарантий, что после нескольких тысяч вычислений, получится даже с округлением, правильный результат.

Comment: всегда округлять в большую сторону хоть и выгодно банку, но применяется в "нечестных банках". Обычно подобное округление либо явно прописано в соглашениях, либо применяется "бухгалтерское округление". В нем смотрят на округляемую цифру - если она равна пяти, то округляют в "парную сторону". То есть 1.5 -> 2, 2.5 -> 3, 3.5 -> 4. это позволяет минимизировать ошибку округления.

Comment: @KoVadim чем приведенный пример отличается от округления к ближайшему? Может вы имели ввиду: 1.5 -> 2, 2.5 -> __2__, 3.5 -> 4

Comment: да, опечатался.  конечно же 2.5 к 2.

Comment: @KoVadim Все верно это называется округление по Гауссу или т.н. банковское округление, его так же используют в траекторном анализе

Answer (score 7):

Каждый сам решает в чем хранить деньги, но наиболее стабильной версией является использования класса `BigDecimal`.

**Преимущества**

1. Точность и значность известна
2. Арифметики и сравнение включены
3. Поддерживается в JDK, JDBC и т.д.
4. Неплохая производительность

Comment: 5. В BigDecimal сделано удобное округление