# Тип данных для валюты

Tags: java, javax.money

Какое решение для валютных операции (транзакции, математика) стоит применять без рисков в production? На данный момент рассматриваю 3 варианта:

1. Свои костыли с BigDecimal и `java.util.Currency`;
2. [Joda Money](http://www.joda.org/joda-money/) - вроде не хуже Joda Time в свое время;
3. Стандарт [javax.money](http://javamoney.github.io/api.html). Как я понимаю его в Java 9 не принимают?

Comment: Похожий вопрос был тут
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/667706/В-чем-хранить-деньги-float-double

Comment: @АнтонМухин, я понимаю почему не стоит хранить деньги в числах с плавающей точкой. В данный момент я хочу понять стоит ли использовать еще не вышедший стандарт JSR 354.