# Счет денег в java

Tags: java, android

Такая ситуация, пишу приложение в котором пользователь указывает необходимое кол-во товара после чего видит итоговую сумму(ценаТовара*КолВо). Проблема в следующем, т.к. в java вот это выражение:

```
double a = 2.0 - 1.1;
```

равно не 0.9 , а вот чему 0.89999999999999991 , то возник такой вопрос, как мне считать общую сумму товара, чтобы избежать подобных неточностей? Цена за единицу товара у меня представлена типом `float`, с ним такие же проблемы? Думал округлять итоговую сумму до двух знаков, но тут тоже кажется могут быть проблемы, и наличие погрешности в расчетах зависит прямо пропорционально от кол-ва умножаемого на цену товара, чем больше тем больше погрешность.

Comment: Для работы с "деньгами" можно использовать тип long с делением на 100 при выводе на экран (в простых случаях), `BigDecimal` для точных расчетов до определенного знака после запятой или специализированные классы/библиотеки ([Java Money](https://github.com/JavaMoney), [Joda Money](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-money)) если требуется многовалютность и специализированные финансовые операции. [Похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/667706/177345)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не все десятичные дроби можно точно представить в виде `double` или `float`. Это связано с особенностью хранения данных в формате с плавающей точкой.

При работе с финансами можно использовать класс [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), который обеспечит необходимую точность.

В Вашем случае:

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal("2.0").subtract(new BigDecimal("1.1"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Зачем такие сложности, начинайте всегда с простого. Тем более вы находитесь на этапе разработки. Храните суммы в типе int, а потом просто поделите на 100 для получения копеек.
Например, стоимость = 52025 руб, что означает 520 руб 25 коп.

Преимущества:

- int удобно хранить значения в БД
- не нужно писать кучу кода для вычислений
- нет проблем с кучей знаков после запятой