# Как вытащить из массива данные с помощью split?

Tags: python, массивы, split

Возникла проблема. Необходимо перебрать список строк и для каждого элемента использовать split, чтобы получить доступ к определённым полям. Категорически не могу понять, как реализовать это на питоне.

Пример данных:

```
['1067 ASUS 3 828,07 3 403,75 ASUS N067 C3903A 2054', '1089 Vendor 3 900,07 3 403,75 Vendor N067 C3903A 2054' ]
```

Нужно извлечь из строки, например, цену 3828,07

Comment: Покажите тот самый список

Comment: приведите пример входных и выходных данных...

Comment: ['1067    ASUS    3 828,07    3 403,75    ASUS N067    C3903A    2054', '1089   Vendor 3 900,07    3 403,75    Vendor N067    C3903A    2054' ] Предположим, мне из этого нужна цена (3828, 07)

Comment: Вы можете привести данные в [самом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/873556/edit) и пояснить откуда взялось число `3828,07`?

Comment: Судя по данным - с помощью split нужное число не вытащить. Тут нужны регулярные выражения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через `split` не получится, т.к. разделитель значений - пробел, и внутри самого нужного значения тоже есть пробелы. Можно попробовать сделать через регулярные выражения. Пример:

```
import re

s = '1067 ASUS 3 828,07 3 403,75 ASUS N067 C3903A 2054'
groups = re.search(r'(\d+) (\w+) ([\d ]+,\d{2}) ([\d ]+,\d{2}) (\w+) (\w+) (\w+) (\d+)', s).groups()
print(groups)
```

Результат:

```
('1067', 'ASUS', '3 828,07', '3 403,75', 'ASUS', 'N067', 'C3903A', '2054')
```

Нужные вам значения вытаскивает шаблон `[\d ]+,\d{2}`. Буквально он означает, что сначала идет набор цифр (`\d`) и пробелов (`+` означает что их 1 или более), потом запятая, потом ровно 2 цифры (количество указывается в фигурных скобках). `\w` в других местах срабатывает на цифру, букву или знак подчеркивания. Круглые скобки означают границы групп.

Подробнее о регулярных выражения можно почитать здесь:
[**Хабр: Регулярные выражения в Python от простого к сложному. Подробности, примеры, картинки, упражнения**](https://habr.com/post/349860/)

Чтобы преобразовать цену в числовой вид, как вариант можно убрать пробелы, заменить запятую на точку, преобразовать к float:

```
print(float(groups[2].replace(' ', '').replace(',', '.')))  # 3828.07
```

Или лучше к формату с фиксированной точкой [**`decimal`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html):

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
getcontext().prec = 2
print(Decimal(groups[2].replace(' ', '').replace(',', '.')))
```

Вот тут можно почитать, почему лучше не хранить деньги в формате с плавающей точкой:
[**В чем хранить “деньги”? Float / Double**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/667706/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%B3%D0%B8-float-double)

Answer (score 0):

не совсем понятен точный функционал, но вот вам пример:

```
data = ['1067 ASUS 3 828,07 3 403,75 ASUS N067 C3903A 2054', '1089 Vendor 3 900,07 3 403,75 Vendor N067 C3903A 2054' ]
```

этот список, как вы видите хранит 2 строки, если вам нужно, например разделить первую строку на слова, то вы можете использовать метод `split`:

```
newData1 = data[0].split(' ')
# теперь newData1 = ['1067', 'ASUS', '3', '828,07', '3', '403,75', 'ASUS', 'N067', 'C3903A', '2054']
```

метод `split` делит строку и возвращает список, где каждый элемент это данные от 1 встречи аргумента до следующей ( если бы мы передали в split 'ASUS': `data[0].split('ASUS')`, то мы бы получили такой список:  `['1067',' 3 828,07 3 403,75 ', ' N067 C3903A 2054']` ) в нем 3 строки от ASUS'a до ASUS'a при этом хочу заметить, что сам делитель опускается (в 1 примере все пробелы ушли, а во вторм ушло слово `ASUS`), если же вам нужно специфичное деление по каким-то сложным критериям, где просто поделить строку на пробелы, или что-то подобное нельзя, то вам придется использовать рег. выражения [вот ссылка на статью на хабре](https://habr.com/post/115825/)

Answer (score 0):

Метод split делит строку по указанному разделителю, создавая из элементов список.  Допустим цена у вас - пятое значение в списке: тогда print(string.split(' ')[5]
  Можете попробовать, также использовать модуль re, очень полезная вещь для поиска в строке по шаблону