# decrypted файла и извлечение из него списка

Tags: python, list

[image: программа дешифрует файл, который хранит в себе список внутрь которого вложено еще несколько списков.]

как обратиться к элементам списка, который оказывается после дешифровки в виде строки в переменной decrypted_content ?

```
with open("Logs.py", "r") as file:
    logg = file.read()
    
decrypted_content = ''

for char in logg:
    decrypted_char = chr(ord(char) - 3)
    decrypted_content += decrypted_char

print(decrypted_content)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя в результате получается список в строке, т.е. тип string "[1,2,3]", тебе нужно вытащить его из строки и тогда уже взаимодействовать с ним, ну или форматируй его как строку.

```
with open("Logs.py", "r") as file:
    logg = file.read()
    
decrypted_content = ''

for char in logg:
    decrypted_char = chr(ord(char) - 3)
    decrypted_content += decrypted_char

print(list(decrypted_content)[0])
```

Comment: А можно поподробнее. Как можно вытянуть список из строки ?

Comment: @ИванГрозный, фигню я тебе присоветовал, он так будет посимвольно элементы выдергивать, глянь вот это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/873556/Как-вытащить-из-массива-данные-с-помощью-split

Comment: @Igor, применение list к строке создает список из отдельных символов строки. Нужно использовать ast.literal_eval как в дублирующем вопросе.