# Как перевести результат вычисления double в понятный формат?

Tags: java, double

## В общем суть вопроса такова

входящие данные 
Числа типа double 
20 000 000 общая сумма

## 3333333.33 ндс с суммы

обработка

## 20 000 000 - 3333333.33 сумма без ндс

результат
1.666666667E7

Как в калькуляторе
мои ожидания Юзеропонятный формат
16 666 666.7

Подскажите класс для математических вычиcлений на java

Comment: Используйте целочисленные типы данных или BigDecimal

Comment: [Как хранить деньги](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/667706/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%B3%D0%B8-float-double)

Comment: В вашем вопросе несколько разных вопросов: 1) Как выводить числа с плавающей точкой. Для этого есть методы `String.format()` и `PrintStream.format()`. Читайте о них справку. 2) Как хранить и обрабатывать денежные суммы. Это зависит от задачи, часто можно обойтись простыми `double`, если нельзя, читайте по ссылке в соседнем  комменте. 3) Какой класс использовать для математических вычислений. Для этого есть класс `java.lang.Math`, обычно его хватает. Если хотите получить более развернутые ответы, задавайте вопросы конкретнее и по одному. Почитайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Для отображения числа используйте `DecimalFormat`. Подробности смотрите в [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)
Класс для математических вычислений [java.lang.Math](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html), также можете посмотреть [StrictMath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StrictMath.html)