# Как обратиться к данным, полученным из таблицы, и произвести операции с ними?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Как обратиться к данным, полученным из таблицы, и произвести операции с ними?

Задача:

Существует таблица `balance`, которая содержит данные (см. ниже), в частности, поле `sum` (сумма).

Задача метода:

- получаем данные из таблицы `Balance`
- получаем конкретные поля, в частности, поле `sum`
- производим операцию с полем `sum` методом `calcBalance` (см. далее пример)
- перезаписываем данные `balanceRepo.save(balance)`

Таблица `Balance`

```java
package com.example.rabbit_new2.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import lombok.*;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Entity
@Table(name = "balance_calc")
@Setter
@Getter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Balance {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "sum")
    private Double sum;

    @Column(name = "tax")
    private Double tax;

    @Column(name = "result")
    private Double result;

    @Column(insertable = true, updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime dateCreated;
    private LocalDateTime dateModified;

    @PrePersist
    void onCreate() {
        this.setDateCreated(LocalDateTime.now());
        this.setDateModified(LocalDateTime.now());
    }

    @PreUpdate
    void onUpdate() {
        this.setDateModified(LocalDateTime.now());
    }
```

Незавершенная логика

```java
public double calcBalance(double sum) {
    double tax = 0.20;
    double resultCalc = sum * tax;
    return resultCalc;
}

public Iterable<Balance> getAllData() {
    return balanceRepo.findAll();
}

public void calcMethodBalance() {
    // получаем данные из таблицы Balance
    // получаем конкретные поля в частности поле sum
    // производим операцию с полем методом calcBalance
    // перезаписываем данные balanceRepo.save(balance)
}
```

Comment: Метод `calcBalance` реализован в классе `BalanceService` который представлен выше (Незавершенная логика). Поле `sum` из таблицы должно обновляться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно предполагается такое решение, в котором можно использовать метод интерфейса `ListCrudRepository` [`saveAll(Iterable<T> entities)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/ListCrudRepository.html#saveAll(java.lang.Iterable)) или, при необходимости немедленного сохранения всей коллекции, [`JpaRepository::saveAllAndFlush`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#saveAllAndFlush(java.lang.Iterable))

```java
public void calcMethodBalance() {
    // получаем данные из таблицы Balance
    List<Balance> balances = balanceRepo.findAll();
    // получаем конкретные поля в частности поле sum
    // производим операцию с полем методом calcBalance
    balances.forEach(b -> b.setSum(calcBalance(b.getSum())));
    // перезаписываем данные
    balanceRepo.saveAll(balances);
}
```

Альтернативное решение-"однострочник":

```java
public void updateBalances() {
    balanceRepo.findAll().forEach(b -> {
        b.setSum(calcBalance(b.getSum()));
        balanceRepo.save(b);
    });
}
```

---

Однако стоит отметить, что использовать тип с плавающей точкой `double` для финансовых вычислений -- не самая лучшая идея из-за ошибок округления, см. ссылки:

- [Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой работают неправильно (2015)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453/)
- [В чем хранить "деньги"? `Float / Double` (2017)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/667706/)

Comment: Благодарю за помощь, единственное использовал вместо 
`List<Balance> balances = balanceRepo.findAll();` вариант с Iterable

`Iterable<Balance> balances = balanceRepo.findAll();`

Comment: Да, `Iterable<E>` - самый [базовый интерфейс](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Iterable.html).